# weather causing power loss

Tags: engine, troubleshooting

Why would my engine lose power when the weather temperature gets warmer. While driving the vehicle will not have as much power when it gets warm or hot.

Comment: Can you give us some information about the car (year/make/model/mileage)? Also, if you could give us an idea of what you mean by warm/hot v. what cold is? Someone in Alaska will surely have a much different idea of what hot/cold is compared to someone who lives in Egypt. Do you usually fill up at the same place? What maintenance have you done to the vehicle. All of this stuff will help us help you. :D

Answer (score 2):

To some extent, all combustion engines lose power in warmer conditions. Cold air is denser, and contains more oxygen, so more fuel can be burned, resulting in more power.

Is it an incremental change in power, or do you notice that over a certain temperature, there is a large noticeable drop in power?